# How Stateful DoFn determines key to partition states

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In following [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html), it is noted that stateful `DoFn`'s state is partitioned per key per window. How is this key determined by given `DoFn`?

For example, if we were to create our own custom `CombinerFn`, we would need to maintain `CombiningState` per key. Is this purely determined by the fact that input to `DoFn` is `KV`? Ex. `Dofn<KV<Key, Value>, Out>`

Comment: I've added an answer.  TLDR: Yes, you're correct. Let me know if I should delve deeper on anything.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The `KV` value in Beam (along with tuples in the Python SDK) is a special type that is encoded to allow the runner to recognize the key for each element.

So: yes, Beam will perform any key-based operations based on the key in the `KV`.

Comment: DoFn is a mapping function so Input/Output signature should not have a special meaning unlike CombineFn. My question given DoFn as a mapper (performs mapping from input to 0 to many output), determines partitioning key? Ex we don't bound DoFn's input to be KV.

Comment: I see. Yes, so when a DoFn is stateful, then it must receive a keyed input. I am pretty sure your pipeline will error out if you try to have a stateful DoFn without a KV type as input.